# Multiplication Table of a number

Tags: cobol

I'm totally new with COBOL. So can anyone help me with my code I want to print out the value of number X and the user should give this value. The Code should be:
"Please give a number FROM 1 TO 9"
For example number 7 will be given
the result must be

```
7 * 1 = 7
7 * 2 = 14
until
7 * 9 = 63
```

```
     *****************************************************************
     * Program name:    MT01                               
     * Original author: MYNAME                                
     *
     * Maintenance Log                                              
     * Date      Author        Maintenance Requirement               
     * --------- ------------  --------------------------------------- 
     * 01/01/08 MYNAME  Created for COBOL class         
     *                                                               
     *****************************************************************
      IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
      PROGRAM-ID.  MT01.
      AUTHOR. MYNAME. 
      INSTALLATION. COBOL DEVELOPMENT CENTER. 
      DATE-WRITTEN. 01/01/08. 
      DATE-COMPILED. 01/01/08. 
      SECURITY. NON-CONFIDENTIAL.
     *****************************************************************
      ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. 
      DATA DIVISION. 
      FILE SECTION. 
      WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
      01 X PIC 99.
      01 INPUTT PIC 9.
      01 RESULT PIC 9(3).
      PROCEDURE DIVISION.

      STEP0.
          PERFORM STEP1.
          PERFORM STEP2.
       

      STEP1.
          DISPLAY "Please give a number FROM 1 TO 9"
          ACCEPT INPUTT.
          

      STEP2.
          MOVE 0 TO X
          PERFORM VARYING X FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL X > 12
          END-PERFORM
          GO TO STEP3.
          

      STEP3.
          COMPUTE RESULT = X * INPUTT 
          DISPLAY INPUTT " * " X " = " RESULT.

          STOP RUN.
```

---

After applying the changes given by @Rick Smith, I compiled my PGM and got this MSG
`MT01.cob:34: warning: inline PERFORM without imperative statement used [-Wdialect]`.

When I tried to execute `./MT01`, nothing happened :(

The Code after editing

```
      *****************************************************************
  * Program name:    MT01                               
  * Original author: MYNAME                                
  *
  * Maintenence Log                                              
  * Date      Author        Maintenance Requirement               
  * --------- ------------  --------------------------------------- 
  * 01/01/08 MYNAME  Created for COBOL class         
  *                                                               
  *****************************************************************
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.  MT01.
   AUTHOR. MYNAME. 
   INSTALLATION. COBOL DEVELOPMENT CENTER. 
   DATE-WRITTEN. 01/01/08. 
   DATE-COMPILED. 01/01/08. 
   SECURITY. NON-CONFIDENTIAL.
  *****************************************************************
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. 
   DATA DIVISION. 
   FILE SECTION. 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01 X PIC 99.
   01 INPUTT PIC 9.
   01 RESULT PIC 9(3).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

   STEP0.
       PERFORM STEP1.
       PERFORM STEP2.
       STOP RUN.

   STEP1.
       DISPLAY "Please give a number FROM 1 TO 9"
       ACCEPT INPUTT.
       
   STEP2.
       PERFORM VARYING X FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL X > 12
       PERFORM STEP3
       END-PERFORM.
       
   STEP3.
       COMPUTE RESULT = X * INPUTT 
       DISPLAY INPUTT " * " X " = " RESULT.
```

Answer (score 1):

On the line after `PERFORM STEP2.`, add either of the statements `GOBACK.` or `STOP RUN.`

Remove the line `MOVE 0 TO X` because `X` will be initialized to `1` in the following `PERFORM` statement.

Between the lines `PERFORM VARYING ...` and the `END-PERFORM`, add the line `PERFORM STEP3`. This will cause an output for each of the `X` values of `01` through `12`.

Insert a `.` after the `END-PERFORM` and remove the `GO TO STEP3.` statement.

Remove the final `STOP RUN.` statement.

---

There is, apparently, a **bug** in the compiler. The updated code compiles and runs when checked for full ANSI COBOL 85 conformance on my Micro Focus compiler.

The problem appears to be that the imperative statement `PERFORM STEP3` at line 29 is not being recognized as an imperative statement within the inline `PERFORM`.

The workaround is to change `STEP2` to either of the following:

```
   STEP2.
       PERFORM STEP3 VARYING X FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL X > 12.
       
   STEP3.
       COMPUTE RESULT = X * INPUTT 
       DISPLAY INPUTT " * " X " = " RESULT.
```

or

```
   STEP2.
       PERFORM VARYING X FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL X > 12
           COMPUTE RESULT = X * INPUTT 
           DISPLAY INPUTT " * " X " = " RESULT
       END-PERFORM.
```

by replacing `PERFORM STEP3` with the code from the `STEP3` paragraph.